# docker-compose nginx and php-fpm need to share code folder?

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose

Why every tutorial that I find on the web always share the code folder between the two machines?

If i'm setting two different machines, its the same that have two physical machines, let's say nginx server on california and php server in florida.

On my understanding, the fastcgi protocol is sending the data through the networks right?

Thats why we are using IP:PORT right?

So nginx ask the machine that understand php to process the data sending to that IP:PORT through fastcgi and getting the processed response to show to the browser right?

Or am I crazy?

Comment: Its usually better to give us some code of what you are trying, but from what you are saying, I don't really think a shared code folder is required for `nginx` + `php-fpm` as such. Then again, we can't be sure unless you share what it is that you trying.

Answer (score 0):

Having made the same journey through these tutorials, here my view:

- **php-fpm** is only the processor for php files, cannot serve static files. For php calls only, php-fpm would technically be enough but the php-fpm container cannot handle multiple requests even if the php-fpm itself is capable to do so
- **nginx** plays the role of a webserver and load balancer, generally a socket (via volume) to communicate to php, and is also delivering static files

So, the shared code is necessary for the entrypoint to php files and having the static files to serve while php-fpm is using code for execution.

*Suggestions to improve this answer welcome.*

References here:

- [php-fpm and nginx on linode.com](https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/serve-php-php-fpm-and-nginx/)
- [nextcloud using the fpm image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nextcloud/?tab=description)